# How do set Chrome to keep trying to download opened tabs until connection is available?

Tags: google-chrome

It used to do that, but not anymore. I'm interested in both mobile Chrome and regular desktop Chrome.

It looks like Chrome does that only if the tab is focused. It will not try to download background tabs, am I right?

Comment: Are you talking about when the tabs are restored from a previous session?

Comment: No, I have a tab on a site that periodically reloads itself, I'm not sure why, it's not my own. When it does that and there's no connection, I get an error. When connection is available again, chrome doesn't try to refresh the page, unless I focus the tab.